# Garbage characters after regex_replace

Tags: c++, boost, boost-xpressive

I am using boost xpressive regex_replace . After the replace I get garbage characters at the end of the string

```
std::wstring wEsc(L"fxSSyrpng");
std::wstring wReplaceByText(L"tiff");
std::wstring searchText(L"fx");

wsregex regExp;
try
{
    regExp = wsregex::compile( searchText );
}
catch ( regex_error &/*error*/ )
{
    throw ;
}
catch (...)
{
    throw ;
}
std::wstring strOut;
strOut.reserve( wEsc.length() + wReplaceByText.length() );
std::wstring::iterator it = strOut.begin();
boost::xpressive::regex_replace( it, wEsc.begin() , wEsc.end(), regExp, 
wReplaceByText,   regex_constants::match_not_null  );
```

Comment: You probably confused `reserve` with `resize`. After `reserve` this condition `strOut.begin() == strOut.end()` is true, so how do you want to write data by `it` ? You cannot, output iterator can give you the access to element which exists and modify it, but in your case `it` points to nothing - `strOut` is empty.

Comment: perfect ..thanks ..can u post it as answer, so I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `reserve` string `strOut` has still 0 elements. So `strOut.begin() == strOut.end()` is true, and `it` points to nothing. If you want to use output iterator to write data in `regex_replace`, `it` must point to memory with enough room to store all data. You can fix it by calling `resize` instead of `reserve`.

Another solution is to employ `back_inserter` to do this job (`operator=` on this iterator push data into `string`), then `it` is unnecessary, and the code looks like:

```
std::wstring strOut;
boost::xpressive::regex_replace( std::back_inserter(strOut), wEsc.begin() , wEsc.end(), regExp, 
wReplaceByText,   boost::xpressive::regex_constants::match_not_null  );
```